# Metadata version mismatch for ng bootstrap module

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ng-bootstrap

I have an angular2 project.

> ```
> npm version: 5.6.0 
> node version: 9.5.0
> ```

I get the follwoing error when I run ng serve. What am I doing wrong?

> ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module
>   /Users/naik/dev/company/admin/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/index.d.ts,
>   found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in
>   /Users/naik/dev/company/admin/src/app/app.module.ts,
>   resolving symbol AppModule in
>   /Users/naik/dev/company/admin/src/app/app.module.ts,
>   resolving symbol AppModule in
>   /Users/naik/dev/company/admin/src/app/app.module.ts

Below are my dependencies in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "^0.5.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ngui/datetime-picker": "^0.16.2",
    "amplitude": "^3.5.0",
    "angular2-tag-input": "^1.2.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fontawesome": "^4.7.2",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "1.5.4",
    "ngx-quill-editor": "^2.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.90",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslib": "^1.8.0",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0"
  }
```

Comment: It means that ng-bootstrap library was built with angular^5 but you use angular^4

Comment: You can do `npm list --depth=0` to see which version of `ng-bootstrap` is installed. You also need to install Bootstrap 4 (at least the CSS).

Comment: @ConnorsFan @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0

Comment: That version requires Angular 5. You can try `npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5 --save-exact` to force the exact beta version (which was compatible with Angular 4).

Comment: Thanks so much ! @ConnorsFan. That worked !!!